# ASP.NET Engine for E-commerce

Tags: .net, asp.net, e-commerce

Can you advice me good free ASP.NET engine for E-commerce?

Comment: Do you mean free as in open source? Or just free as in no licence fee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/). From their *Overview* page:

> nopCommerce is a fully customizable
>   shopping cart. It's stable and highly
>   usable. nopCommerce is an open source
>   e-commerce solution that is ASP.NET
>   3.5 based with a MS SQL 2005 (or higher) backend database.